# Finding the equation of a plane

Tags: calculus

> Find the equation of a plane which those 3 points $A=(1,0,3),B=(1,1,1),C=(1,-3,2)$ are on it, and find the distance from the origin.

So I need to find 2 independent vectors to find the normal vector.

$\vec{BA}=(0,-1,2)$ and $\vec{BC}=(0,-4,1)$ taking $N=\vec{BA}\times\vec{BC}=7\hat{i}$

So the equation of the plane is $7x=D$, to find $D$ we place one of the points to get $D=7$ so the distance from the origin is $7$ and the equation of the plane is $7x=7$?

Have I got it right?

Comment: The plane is $x=1$ and the distance is $1$

Comment: @DavidQuinn I must divide by 7?

Comment: Not if you don't want to. But it's the same equation anyway, and the distance is still $1$

Comment: @DavidQuinn why is it 1? I understand that I got a plane that is free to move on the Y and Z axis, but lays on $x=7$

Comment: $x=7$ does not satisfy the equation $7x=7$

Comment: @DavidQuinn so in general for a given $Ax+By+Cz=D$ I can not say that $D$ is the distance from the origin? thanks

Comment: No the distance is $\frac{D}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the plane is $$(x-1)\times 7i=0 => (x-1)i=0$$